# Show a holomorphic function on unit disc with with $|f'(z) - f'(0)| < |f'(0)|$ is injective

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on the following question:

If $f(z)$ is holomorphic on the unit disc with $|f'(z) - f'(0)| < |f'(0)|$ for all $z$ in the unit disc, then f is injective.

I've had several thoughts, but I don't really seem to be getting anywhere.

I defined a new function $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{f'(0)} - z$.  Then $|g'(z)| < 1$.

I picked two distinct points, $z_1$ and $z_2$, took a path between them, and integrated $g'$ along a path between them.  But the best estimate I got from this was $|g(z_1) - g(z_2)| \le |z_1 - z_2|$.  If I has a strict equality, I can see how this would be enough to show that $f(z_1) \not = f(z_2)$, but I don't see how to make the inequality strict.

I thought about seeing if I could use the Schwarz lemma somehow instead, but I don't see how I would know that $g(0) = 0$ or $g'(0) = 0$, and even if I could so that I'm not sure that Schwarz would be useful here.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

We can write

$$f(w)-f(z)= (w-z)\int_0^1f'(z+(w-z)t)\,dt$$ $$ = (w-z)[\int_0^1(f'(z+(w-z)t)-f'(0))\,dt + f'(0)\,].$$

But the last integrand, in absolute value, is always less than $|f'(0)|.$ Thus the expression in brackets is nonzero, showing $f(w)\ne f(z).$

Comment: You can edit any post on the site

Comment: is there a typo in your answer?

Comment: I reformatted the answer. Is it OK now? (This may have been my first post at MSE.)